# What to block a hole with to stop mice getting in?

Tags: walls, hole, mice

I have heard rustling sounds coming from my exterior walls, which I am assuming is mice (or some other rodent) scurrying around in the hollow wall.

I have found a hole about 2 inches in diameter in my electricity meter box where a thick electrical cable enters the house, which I think might be where the mice are getting into the walls.

What can I use to block the hole that the mice won't be able to move or chew through?

Comment: The hole is *in* your meter box? Isn't your meter box closed off, aside from the opening to your house and the service mast above?

Comment: No, the electricity cable come from the ground into the bottom of the box, and then into the house, and there are gaps around both holes easily big enough for a small rodent to squeeze in.  I'm in the UK, so maybe it is different to elsewhere in the world?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When sealing a hole around an electrical entry cable, the best product to use is Plasduct. It is a putty like material, gray in color. You will find it in most electrical departments at the box stores or your local hardware store.  Use it just like modeling clay, work it a bit to make it pliable, then stuff it into the hole around the cable as deeply as possible. I have never seen rodents or insects get through this stuff.

Comment: +1 If you don't find it in the electrical department, check the HVAC supplies, since this is also used on the holes from refrigerant lines.

Comment: I've never heard of "Plasduct", but it sounds just like [Duct Seal](http://www.idealindustries.com/prodDetail.do?prodId=duct-seal&div=5&l1=accessories) which is a product from [Ideal Industries](http://www.idealindustries.com/).

Comment: yes, same type of product.

Comment: Thanks.  I have not heard of this type of product, but it sounds perfect.  I'm in the UK, but hopefully there will be a similar product here that I can find.  Thanks again!

Comment: In the UK, this putty is called 'Plumber's Mait', and it did the job perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I fill the hold with caulk, then stick pins in it to deter mice from coming near. then cover with plaster. then tile the floor.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score -2):

Quickest and easiest way is to stuff the hole with steel wool. You can also put screening material or similar metalwork over the hole.

Comment: In most cases, steel wool is good for sealing a hole from pests. But when that hole includes 100+amp wiring, I'd recommend against anything that can wear the insulation and react badly to electrical current.

Comment: steel wool looks so cool when it burns though!  lol

Comment: If you can find it, copper wool is good. (Amazon sells it.) It won't rust, and mice won't go through it. If not, steel wool works, and is far cheaper. It is a bad idea for holes that have wires running through them though.

Comment: Fine steel wool can even ignite with low voltage: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YjYecQeQ7_A

Comment: I thought he was talking about the hole coming into his house and missed it about the electrical box.